# Terraform module for storage management policy, selective actions

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-storage, terraform-provider-azure

I am attempting to use the terraform azurerm_storage_management_policy resource by way of a module for so I don't have to repeat myself as much in my code.

I have a situation where I need to set all of the following on some folders:
`tier_to_cool_after_days_since_modification_greater_than    = var.days_to_cool tier_to_archive_after_days_since_modification_greater_than = var.days_to_archive delete_after_days_since_modification_greater_than          = var.days_to_delete`

But on some folders I only need to set the `delete_after_days_since_modification_greater_than`

I'd like to do this without defining a resource in my main config for this environment, but I'm not finding a way to do that. I see a github request for terraform to add a -1, but that was shot down.

Is there a way I'm missing to not have to define all three when I have a module that lists all three?

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, to set all of the following on some folders and only set the `delete_after_days_since_modification_greater_than` on some other folders. You can define the virtual folders in two partitions and use the `for` loop to iterate the virtual folders in each rule. You can filter the selecting folders with `prefix_match`.

Here is a working example for your reference.

```
locals {
  folderlist1= ["test1","test2","test3"] 
  folderlist2 = [ "foo1","foo2"]

  list1 = [
      for a in local.folderlist1: 
      "container1/${a}"
  ]

  list2 = [
      for b in local.folderlist2: 
      "container1/${b}"
  ]

}


output "result1" {
    value = local.list1
}

output "result2" {
  value = local.list2
}


resource "azurerm_storage_management_policy" "example" {
  storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.example.id


  rule {
    name    = "rule1"
    enabled = true
    filters {
      prefix_match = local.list1
      blob_types   = ["blockBlob"]
    }
    actions {
      base_blob {
        tier_to_cool_after_days_since_modification_greater_than    = 10
        tier_to_archive_after_days_since_modification_greater_than = 50
        delete_after_days_since_modification_greater_than          = 100
      }
      # snapshot {
      #   delete_after_days_since_creation_greater_than = 30
      # }
    }
  }
  
  rule {
    name    = "rule2"
    enabled = true
    filters {  
      prefix_match = local.list2 
      blob_types   = ["blockBlob"]
    }
    actions {
      base_blob {
        # tier_to_cool_after_days_since_modification_greater_than    = 11
        # tier_to_archive_after_days_since_modification_greater_than = 51
        delete_after_days_since_modification_greater_than          = 101
      }
      # snapshot {
      #   delete_after_days_since_creation_greater_than = 31
      # }
    }
  }
}
```

Result

[image]